# Xcode 8.3.3 autolayout - view is disappearing runtime when setting constraints

Tags: xcode, autolayout, xcode8

I'm trying to make a divider, so what I do is:

1) Make a new View

2) Change the background to the color I want the divider to be

3) Control click and center it horizontally on a label on top of it

4) Compile, my view is gone.

5) Remove constraints, compile, my view is there.

6) Add left and right constraint for autosize, compile, view is gone.

---

It also states that the height of my view is ambiguous.

How can the view be gone by merely constraining it?

Screenshot:
[image]

Comment: The height **is** ambiguous. It doesn't have any content so there is no `intrinsic content size` and you are not telling it what height to be as you have not added a height constraint to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is my output I tried in swift using Xcode and tried setting constraints as I do

[image: My added view]

[image: Constraints of view]

[image: Simulator output]

[image: Try giving height and width or aspect ratio to vary according to size of screen]

Answer (score 2):

Your view does not disappear. It just getting zero size.
When you remove constraints iOS won't layout your view that is why it's size not changing.

In he last case with leading/trailing constrains your view calculates its width depending on it's superview width, but since the system can't calculate height, it changes it to zero.

Since other views like labels and images are meant for content they have an intrinsically defined size the system won't resize them to zero, but to their content size.